# How to update based Additional Information tab on the selected variation

Tags: javascript, php, function, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I find a code for update based additional information tab on the select variation
here is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity', 'bbloomer_dynamic_atts_variation' );
  
function bbloomer_dynamic_atts_variation() {
   global $product;
   if ( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) return;
    wc_enqueue_js( " 
      $('input.variation_id').change(function(){
         if( $(this).val() && $(this).val() > 0  ) {   
            $('form.variations_form').find('.variations select').each( function( index, el ){
               var current_select_id = $(el).attr('id');
               var current_select_val = $(el).find('option:selected').text();
               $('.woocommerce-product-attributes-item--attribute_'+current_select_id+' td p').text(current_select_val);
            });
         } 
      });
   " );
}
```

there are two problems in this code

one problem is after selecting variations from combo boxes, if I click on the reset variations button, It does not return to the first state that showed all the product attributes in the product specifications.
that means The table of additional specifications changes only when we have another choice. And it will not return to the previous state.
my next (second) problem is All selections must be done up to the last selectable option to update the product specification tables. but I want a code for changing (updating) product specifications for each selected item. that means after each selection updating product specification texts According to my choices.